# How many $g$'s does a mass see as it impacts and compresses a spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, spring

Essentially, I'm designing a drop test, and to simplify my problem I've modeled the system as a known mass $m$ being dropped from a set height $h$ onto a spring (set $k$), compressing it ($x$). How many $g$'s does the mass see upon impact, when the spring is fully compressed?

Using energy equations to solve for $x$ is simple enough (there are even online examples like this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cszUKo8J7aI))

Once I've solved for $x$, does it make sense to use $a = kx/m$ --> $g$'s $= a/g = a / 9.81m/s^2$?

I have one more question: If using the method above is reasonable, it seems that the smaller the mass, the greater the acceleration and the greater the $g$'s; how is it possible? I would have thought that the smaller the mass, the less $g$'s are felt on impact.

Comment: Your method for finding the maximum acceleration is correct. For your second question, if $m$ is smaller, then $x$ will also be smaller, so it is not "obvious" that the acceleration will be bigger - do the algebra yourself! Another way to think about the whole question is that while it is in contact with the spring, the mass is moving in simple harmonic motion. If $m$ is smaller, then the frequency of the SHM will be higher but the amplitude will be smaller, so again it is not "obvious" how the acceleration changes.

Comment: I think it would be better to say that the spring impact decelerates the object.

Answer (score 1):

> Once I've solved for $x$, does it make sense to use $a = kx/m$ --> $g$'s $= a/g = a / 9.81m/s^2$?

Yes, according to the [Wikipedia definition of g-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force), it is common to express an acceleration in terms of $g$. I.e. an acceleration of $98.1\,\text{ms}^{-2}$ can be said to be an acceleration of "10 g". Your equation translates this correctly by dividing the acceleration by $g$.

> If using the method above is reasonable, it seems that the smaller the mass, the greater the acceleration and the greater the $g$'s; how is it possible? I would have thought that the smaller the mass, the less $g$'s are felt on impact.

No, your intuition is wrong - a smaller mass does experience a larger acceleration, but not simply because of the equation $a=\frac{kx}{m}$.

If you imagine being in a very heavy metal ship, dropped onto a large spring, you are going to not feel that much acceleration as there is a larger inertia to accelerate, and although there is a larger force from the spring, it is not that much larger than for someone in a small car.

Maybe it is easier to see from the maths...

The GPE is converted to elastic potential:

$$mgh = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$

This means $x \propto \sqrt m$.

Your equation say that $a \propto \frac{x}{m} \propto \frac{\sqrt m}{m} \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$, so as the mass increases, the max acceleration decreases.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's making sense to me now. So would it be correct to state that a smaller mass is *easier* to move/accelerate against Earth's gravity?

Comment: @Hunter: yes, it is easier to pick up light objects than heavy ones. That should comport with every-day experience. per the answer, a good technique when faced with lack of intuition is to imagine the extremes: if you drop a ship or a ELE asteroid onto a spring, it's not going to accelerate much, but if you drop something small, say a gnat or a virus, on the spring, it stops pretty quickly.